# grails external lib location

Tags: grails

we work on grails and have many projects. But we have a situation that many of the projects use same lib jar files. The problems with this approach is management of libraries jar files. For example, If any of the library changes, we need to remove and copy that lib jar in every project. So how can I set external lib location for grails, so that a single lib location can be shared by different grails application.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use Maven to deal with the Jar and then use the [dependency resolution](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.7%20Dependency%20Resolution) to get the Jar into the Grails apps.

For example if you uncomment the mavenCentral() line you can use a jar like the following:

```
dependencies {
    runtime('com.googlecode.jslint4java:jslint4java-ant:2.0.0') {

    }
}
```

When ever you need to upgrade the jar it is very easy to go and update this listing to the new version.